# Set line-height to a percentage of the screen

Tags: html, css

I have a website which basically consists of 5 list items. Say my body's width and height are 400px. I'd like to be able to spread the items of the list over the full body height (regardless of what the value of body height is).

I was looking into the `line-height` property, but I can't seem to figure out how to use that properly. If I change the `margin` property of the `li` to `1em 0;`, the list items get spread out a bit. Entering a % value for margin spreads out the list way beyond the screen limit.

How can I spread the list items over the complete screen, regardless of what the height of the screen is?

The HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, mobile" />

        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <division id="container">
            <ul>
                <li><label id="namelabel">Naam</li>
                <li><img id="photo" src="" /></li>
                <li><label id="price">12.29</label></li>
                <li><label id="deltime">3</label></li>
                <li><img id="logo" src="x.png"/></li>
            </ul>
        </divion>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS file:

```
body {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

li {

    margin: 100%;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

#container {
}

#logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: use tables instead, they are more effective and handy

Comment: It would make more sense to place `width: 400px; height: 400px` on `#container` instead of the body...

Comment: what's up with the "division" tag?

Comment: @MarcAudet I agree but when I change that, the website shows like nothing has happened... That's why I changed it to the body

Comment: @koala_dev HTML5's equivalent to `<div>`

Comment: @Joetjah I can't find any reference on google

Comment: @koala_dev You are actually right, my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may be close to what you need:

```
#container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: inherit;
}
li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 20%;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: beige;
}

#logo {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The container block sets the height, and you want that height to pass through to `ul` by inheritance, and then to `li` as 20%, since you have 5 elements.

I changed the `<division>` tag to `<div>` (maybe you intended `<section>` instead).

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/gwh9L/

Be careful about zero-ing out margins and padding on `ul` and `li`, otherwise extra white space becomes an issue.

You can also scale this to the view port depending on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
html {height:100%;}
body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
ul {list-style-type:none; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
li {height:20%; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WrJvA/